# How pass password with Ansible?

Tags: linux, command-line, ansible

I'm trying to run this task in Ansible:

```
- name: zabbix database
  shell:
    chdir: /usr/share/doc/zabbix-server-mysql-4.0.33/
    cmd:  zcat create.sql.gz | mysql -u muhannad -p zabbix_db
```

When `zcat create.sql.gz` runs it requires to enter the password, and Ansible stuck because it's waiting to enter the password, how can I set the password from client-side?

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/mysql/mysql_query_module.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the expect module to specify password input.

```yaml
- name: Provide password 
  expect:
     command: zcat /usr/share/doc/zabbix-server-mysql-4.0.33/create.sql.gz | mysql -u muhannad -p zabbix_db
     responses:
        'password': "{{mysql_password}}"
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not `zcat` that's prompting for password, it's `mysql`.

You can pass the password via `-p` command line switch, for example if your password is `mypassword`:

```
mysql -u muhannad -pmypassword zabbix_db
```

Note however that this will make your password visible in `ps`, among other things. Alternatively, you might prefer to specify the password via environment or via `my.cnf`.

Comment: yes it's from MySQL and it works, but for commands doesn't support the password option?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ansible Vault to manage sensitive data.

For detailed instructions, please refer to the [official documents of Vault | Ansible Documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_vault.html).

Create an encrypted (Encrypted) file.

```
 $ ansible-vault create foo.yml
```

Edit the contents of encrypted files.

```
$ ansible-vault edit foo.yml
```

Change the encryption key (password).

```
$ ansible-vault rekey foo.yml
```

Encrypt existing plaintext files

```
$ ansible-vault encrypt foo.yml
```

Decrypt the encrypted file.

```
$ ansible-vault decrypt foo.yml
```

View the contents of the encrypted file.

```
$ ansible-vault view foo.yml
```